# Font will not set in reportlab text object

Tags: python, reportlab

Im having trouble getting the font to set in reportlab. I set the canvas and the text object to Courier, size 9, but when I open the resulting document the text is all Ariel, size 12. I know exactly the space I have for the text and how it should fit with that font and size.

```
for columns in [roadList_split[pos:pos+4] for pos in xrange(0, len(roadList_split), 4)]:
page = canvas.Canvas(os.path.join(out_path, r'IndexPage%s.pdf'%count), pagesize = letter)
page.setFont = ('Courier', 9)
text = page.beginText(.6875*inch, 10.5*inch)
text.setFont = ('Courier', 9)
for column in columns:
    text.textLines(column, trim = 0)
    text.moveCursor(1.875*inch,-10*inch)
page.drawText(text)
page.line(2.3681*inch, 0.5*inch, 2.3681*inch, 10.5*inch)
page.line(4.2431*inch, 0.5*inch, 4.2431*inch, 10.5*inch)
page.line(6.125*inch, 0.5*inch, 6.125*inch, 10.5*inch)
count += 1
page.save()
```

Comment: `setfont` is a `canvas` _method_ not an attribute. You need to call it using something like `page.setFont('Courier New', 9)` instead of `page.setFont = ('Courier New', 9)`. Likewise for textobjects.

Comment: Well all I can say to that sir is, derp. Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes...